# Angular $http service wait until data returned

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-http

I created this http service:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("inspectionReview").factory("inspectionReviewServices", ["$http", "config", inspectionReviewServices]);

    function inspectionReviewServices($http, config) {
        var serviceAddress = config.baseUrl + "api/InspectionReview/";
        var service = {
            getValues: getValues
        };
        return service;

        function getValues(objectId, frequencyId) {
            return $http.get(serviceAddress + "getValuesByObjectTypeId/" + objectId + "/" + frequencyId);
        }    
    }
})();
```

And here I use it in controller to get data:

```
function checkInspection() {
    var frequencyId = 5;
    inspectionReviewServices.getValues($scope.object.Id, frequencyId).then(function (result) {
       $scope.someData = result.data;
    });
}
```

When I call function `checkInspection` I need to wait until $scope.someData property is populated by data and only after it populated by data only then further  rows can be executed.Currently I get promise and code executed further.

**EDIT(according to the Darren's answer):**

I changed my service and function that calls service:

```
function getValues2(objectId, frequencyId) {
    return $http.get(serviceAddress + "getValuesByObjectTypeId/" + objectId + "/" + frequencyId).then(function (result) {
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

and here  is function that calls for service in controller:

```
    function checkInspectionReviewValidety() {
        var frequencyId = 5;
        return inspectionReviewServices.getValues2($scope.object.Id, frequencyId)
        }
```

But still I dont get desired result.

How can I change checkInspection function to make it wait until $scope.someData property is populated by data?

Comment: Well, you can't. Put logic that needs `result.data` in `then` block.

Comment: You have to pass in the work you want to do as a function.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.then`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) on the $http service method

```
$http.get(serviceAddress + "getValuesByObjectTypeId/" + objectId + "/" + frequencyId).then(function() {
  // Populate items from callback 
});
```

Comment: All that will do is move where the promise is resolved - it doesn't make it synchronous so the OP will be left with the same issue.

Comment: I made some edit to the question.Can you see it now please?

Comment: @DarrenDavies, as Lex pointed out, it makes absolutely no difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. The whole aspect of [promises](https://promisesaplus.com/) is to handle the async request and execute when the promise is resolved/rejected. If you want some piece of code to execute after data is filled up please move that part of the code into `.then` block.